# How to redirect to external URI in Nuxt.js with post data?

Tags: nuxt.js

How can I redirect to external url from my Nuxt.js page and send post data with this redirection?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with those 2 actions?

Comment: Actually it is one action, redirection to an external url with post data.
Then I will receive this data in an PHP page and do some processes on them. @kissu

Answer (score 0):

For this, you could do the following

- use a link to reach the PHP website with something like `<a href="http://test.com?test=hello&another=world">Go somewhere</a>`
- on `test.com`, the PHP server will get those URL queries and pass them
- to another page, which will make the POST

PS: of course, a redirect is possible too but let's focus on getting this right with a bare link at first.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your answer.
However, I sent a bearer token as a parameter, so I need to send it as a post from nuxt.js, is that possible?

Comment: @naw You can pass it as a query params in during the redirection (not the best) but you wanted to have a redirect so I guess there is no alternative.